# In Java, is it possible to use some sort of while loop (or anything) to determine the amount of prompts for input?

Tags: java, loops, input, while-loop

```
public static void main (String [] args)
{
    // declare variables, capture input

    String input, name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please " +
                          "enter your first and last name.");
    double testScore1, testScore2, testScore3, average;

    // capture input, cast, and validate input

    input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is the score " +
                                        "of your first test?");
    testScore1 = Double.parseDouble(input);

    while (testScore1 < 1 || testScore1 > 100)
    {
        input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("This test score is not " +
                "between 1 and 100. \nPlease enter a test score in " +
                "this range:");

        testScore1 = Double.parseDouble(input); 
    }

    input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is the score " +
                                        "of your second test?");
    testScore2 = Double.parseDouble(input);

    while (testScore2 < 1 || testScore2 > 100)
    {
        input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("This test score is not " +
                "between 1 and 100. \nPlease enter a test score in " +
                "this range:");

        testScore2 = Double.parseDouble(input); 
    }

    input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is the score " +
                                        "of your third test?");
    testScore3 = Double.parseDouble(input);

    while (testScore3 < 1 || testScore3 > 100)
    {
        input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("This test score is not " +
                "between 1 and 100. \nPlease enter a test score in " +
                "this range:");

        testScore3 = Double.parseDouble(input);
    }

    // calculate average and display output

    average = (testScore1 + testScore2 + testScore3)/3; 

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, name + ", your average score is: " + average);

}
```

First off, I'm a beginner programmer. My terminology and jargon are quite lacking, so bear with me.

I'm writing a program to capture 3 test scores then validate them using a while loop (must be within the 1-100 range). The test scores are then averaged and the output displays the average. Pretty simple stuff.

I'm wanting to find a way, if possible, to capture the number of test scores, then from there, capture each actual score. For example, the program asks "How many tests are being computed for average?", then take that number and have it be the same amount of times the program prompts, "Please enter test score (1):" or something along those lines. So for further clarity, if the user typed 4 for number of tests, then the prompt for inputting the score would show up 4 times.

I feel the above code is redundant by using a while loop for each score and at that, limited because the program is only meant for 3 scores. Any help is much appreciated and feel free to critique anything else in the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can.

What you need is a *nested loop*. In pseudo code:

```
while(condition)
{
   int numberOfInput = getInput() ; //get the input from the user

   for(int i =0 ; i < numberOfInput; i++) //iterate for the amount of prompts required
     prompt() ; //get input

}



function prompt
      while (testScore1 < 1 || testScore1 > 100)
      {
        input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("This test score is not " +
                "between 1 and 100. \nPlease enter a test score in " +
                "this range:");

        testScore1 = Double.parseDouble(input); 
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:**Yes,** it is possible. 
 **Option 1:**  Initially ask the user how many scores they are planning on entering, and store that in an int variable. 
For example:

```
  
       Ask user how many scores to enter.
       Check the response, and store it in an int variable.
       Create a double variable to add the scores (initialize it to 0.0)

       Use a for loop, asking for the score;
       Evaluate the score to ensure it's a valid number
         If it's not a valid number, prompt the user again (this is still within 
          the same iteration, not a different iteration)
         If it's a valid number, add it to the total scores variable
       Once loop is exhausted, just divide the two variables (since the total 
         scores is a double, your answer will automatically be a double)
       Display the answer.
```

**Option 2:** Use a sentinel-loop (the user has to enter a letter -usually 'Q' or 'N'- or something to exit the loop)

```
  
       Create an int variable to store total loops (initialize to 0).
       Create a double variable to add the scores (initialize it to 0.0)

       Use a for loop, asking for the score;
       Check if the value is the quit character
        If it is not
          Evaluate the score to ensure it's a valid number
            If it's not a valid number, prompt the user again (this is still within 
            the same iteration, not a different iteration)
          If it's a valid number, add it to the total scores variable and increment 
          the total loops variable by 1.
        If it is
         just divide the two variables (since the total 
         scores is a double, your answer will automatically be a double)
       Display the answer.
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In http://korada-sanath.blogspot.in/p/discussion-on-tech-topics.html, there is a pseudo code which illustrates similar problem with basic Java programming skills. In that in looping section you can simply add a check whether user entered score is in range 1-100 or not. If not, you can decrease loop variable by '1' so that user can enter his score one more time...

For further illustration please add below code in looping section of code present in above mentioned link.

instead of directly assigning user entered value to your testScores array, you can use one temp var and then can assign if user entered score in range.

```
Double temp = Double.parseDouble(br.readLine());
if(temp > 1 && temp < 100) {

    testScores[loopVar] = temp;

} else {

    loopVar--;
}
```